# Create class instance variable into scrapy spider

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to python. I want to create my own class instance `variable_1, variable_2` in to scrapy spider class. The following code is working good.

```
class SpiderTest1(scrapy.Spider):

    name       = 'main run'
    url        = 'url example'  # this class variable working find
    variable_1 = 'info_1'       # this class variable working find
    variable_2 = 'info_2'       # this class variable working find

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [self.url]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        print (f'some process with {self.variable_1}')
        print (f'some prcesss with {self.variable_2}')


# start run the class
process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())   
process.crawl(SpiderTest1())
process.start()
```

But I want to make it class instance variable, so that I do not have to modify variable's value inside spider everytime I run it. I decide to create `def __init__(self, url, varialbe_1, variable_2)` into scrapy spider, and I expect to use `SpiderTest1(url, variable_1, variable_2)` to run it. The following is new code that I expect to result as the code above does, but this is not working good:

```
class SpiderTest1(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'main run'

    # the following __init__ are new change, but not working fine
    def __init__(self, url, variable_1, variable_2):
        self.url = url                 
        self.variable_1 = variable_1
        self.variable_2 = variable_2

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [self.url]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        print(f'some process with {self.variable_1}')
        print(f'some prcesss with {self.variable_2}')

# input values into variables
url        = 'url example'  
variable_1 = 'info_1'       
variable_2 = 'info_2' 

# start run the class
process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())   
process.crawl(SpiderTest1(url, variable_1, variable_2)) #it seem this code doesn't work
process.start()
```

It result:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'url', 'variable_1', and 'variable_2'
```

Thank when anyone can tell how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Common Practices](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html) and [API documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess.crawl), you should call the `crawl` method like this to pass arguments to the spider constructor:

```
process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())   
process.crawl(SpiderTest1, url, variable_1, variable_2)
process.start()
```

**UPDATE:**
The documentation also mentions this form of running the spider:

```
process.crawl('followall', domain='scrapinghub.com')
```

In this case, `'followall'` is the name of the spider in the project (i.e. the value of `name` attribute of the spider class). In your specific case where you define the spider as follows:

```
class SpiderTest1(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'main run'
    ...
```

you would use this code to run your spider using spider name:

```
process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())   
process.crawl('main run', url, variable_1, variable_2)
process.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank, my code is working fine with your way. 
But I find things slightly different from [Common Practices](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html)

this is our code:

`process.crawl(SpiderTest1, url, variable_1, variable_2)`

this is from [Common Practices](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html)

```
process.crawl('followall', domain='scrapinghub.com')
```

The first variable as your suggest is using class's name `SpiderTest1`, but the other one uses string `'followall'`

What does `'followall'`refer to? 
It refers to directory: `testspiders/testspiders/spiders/followall.py` or just the class's variable `name = 'followall'`under `followall.py`

I am asking it because I am still confused when I should call `string` or `class name` in scrapy spider.

Thank.